# WPF re-evaluate style triggers

Tags: wpf, localization, setter, datatrigger, wpf-style

My App supports Localization in English and Spanish. I have a textlabel that depending on the property Age it applies different styles.
For example, if Localization is set to English:

If Age < 18 -> Text = Under age [in colour red]

If Age > 18 -> Text = Over age [in colour green]

If Age == 18 -> Text = On eighteen [in colour blue]

This is working fine with this code:

```
<TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Age,
                    Converter={StaticResource CuttoffConverter}, ConverterParameter=18}"
                             Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Loc strUnderAge}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Age,
                    Converter={StaticResource CuttoffConverter}, ConverterParameter=18}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Loc strOverAge}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Age}" Value="18">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Loc strOnEighteen}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

The localization part, is covered with {Loc XXXXXX} tag and it works fine except for this: **if the language is changed "on-air", this DataTrigger Setter properties are not re-evaluated, so the labels are still displayed in English.**

Is there any way to force to be re-evaluated?

**UPDATE:**

I have updated my Localization library to this one: [WPF Localization Advanced](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249369/Advanced-WPF-Localization) which now supports Styles.
However, now it breakes when compiling the above XAML code. The error says:

> "LocExtension is not valid for Setter.Value. the only supported
>   MarkupExtension types are DynamicResoruceExtension and BindingBase or
>   derived types."

Is there any way to accomplish the same purpose I did with trigger but with any of the suported methods by LocExtension?

Comment: Is your model in which the `strUnderAge` property implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface?

Comment: strUnderAge is not a property. It's a key to get the Value in the corresponding Resource file (depending on the CultureInfo)

Comment: That CodeProject thing claims (I haven't verified the claim) that `Loc` will update if you set `LocalizationManager.UICulture`. Is that what you're doing to change the culture?

Comment: Yes @EdPlunkett . That's exactly what I do.

Answer (score 1):

1. define `strUnderAge` as a property within a class that Implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface.
2. bind the trigger to the `strUnderAge` property.
3. when you change the language raise the `PropertyChanged` event.

Otherwise the trigger can not know that the language has changed.

Comment: Hi google fan, not sure how to do that since I am using a 3rd party Localization solution explained here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30035/Simple-WPF-Localization

Comment: The solution in the link you brought is not suitable for Trigger, the Trigger can not know that the language has changed